# Angular directive for making text appear in a tooltip when a CSS ellipsis is applied, and offsetwidth constantly returns 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to write an angular directive that will turn a tooltip on an element if there if the text inside it is too long and has an ellipsis. I thought this would be simple enough, in that I'd just check the offsetwidth against the scroll width. However, the directive I wrote returns 0 for the offsetwidth and the scrollwidth no matter what element I slap it on. Here is my directive:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('base')
        .directive('offsetWidth', offsetWidth);

    function offsetWidth() {
        var directive = {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'A'
        };

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            var el = element[0];
            console.log('element ', element);
            console.log(el.scrollWidth);
            if (el.offsetWidth < el.scrollWidth) {
                console.log('inside if ', el);
                attrs.tooltipEnable = true;
            } else {
                console.log('inside else');
            }
        }

        return directive;
    }

})();
```

Is there something I'm missing in my code in order for this to work? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`link` function runs when DOM is already compiled and modification of attribute doesn't have required effect. So a way is to add a shared attribute (between tooltip ui bootstrap and current directive) on compilation phase.

```
angular.module('base').directive('offsetWidth',  offsetWidth);

function offsetWidth()  {
  return {
     compile: function ($element, attrs) {
        attrs.tooltipEnable = 'isTooltipEnabled';
        return function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
          // place code here
          // --- for testing:start
          setTimeout(function() {
            // enable tooltip after timeout
            $scope.isTooltipEnabled = true;
            $scope.$applyAsync();
          }, 5000);
          // --- for testing:end 
        };
     },
     scope: false // don't create own scope
  };
}
```

HTML

```
<button tooltip-placement="bottom" 
     uib-tooltip="On the bottom"
     offset-width 
     type="button" 
     class="btn btn-default">Tooltip bottom</button>
```

Comment: setTimeout was the solution, thanks a lot.